# Svelte +Vite: writable store in Typescript, cannot import Writable<T> interface

Tags: typescript, svelte, vite

In a Svelte project scaffolded using Vite I try to write a Svelte store in Typescript; having troubles with importing `Writable<T>` interface like below:

```
import { Writable, writable, derived } from 'svelte/store';
```

This results in the following error in a browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/svelte_store.js?v=16f52463' does not provide an export named 'Writable'.
```

Is there any way to import `Writable<T>` interface in such a setup?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `import type { Writable } from 'svelte/store';`.

Update: From TypeScript 4.5 onwards you should be able to do all imports in one line. So instead of

```
import type { Writable } from 'svelte/store';
import { writable, derived } from 'svelte/store';
```

you can do

```
import { type Writable, writable, derived } from 'svelte/store';
```